# ¿solucion para el error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.?

Tags: php, servidor, dns, redes

primera vez posteando aqui asi que no sean tan duros si me equivoco en algo. el caso es que a un amigo le crearon una pagina web y todo funcionaba bien hasta que le salto un error, mas concreto este error DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. el caso es que yo estoy un poco familiarizado con esto y me pidio que lo ayudara, bien intente las soluciones basicas de youtube por parte del cliente y me sigue saliendo este error. Mi idea es que este error viene por parte del server en el que esta alojada la ip y la pagina, pero no se si sera asi. si alguno de ustedes me lo puede confirmar lo agradeceria ya que mucha exp en esta parte de redes no tengo. un saludo y esta es la pagina en concreto [www.wearit.com.ar](http://www.wearit.com.ar) . desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Ese dominio no está propagado, [verifica aquí](https://dnschecker.org).

Comment: gracias por responder, disculpa la ignorancia pero que querria decir eso?

Comment: Por usar palabras sencillas, ese dominio no parece estar alojado en ningún sitio o bien los registros del mismo están mal configurados. Por lo general tú compras un dominio, pero para alojar contenido debes contratar un servicio de hosting. Da más detalles al respecto. ¿Dónde tienes alojado tu dominio? ¿Verificaste los registros del mismo en el hosting? ¿Tienes acceso a los archivos que tienes subidos en el hosting? Etc

Comment: ah entiendo entiendo. uf esa info dificil que te la consiga ya que mi amigo tiene 0 idea de esto la verdad y si le pregunto no creo que me responda. lo que te puedo decir es que hace 2 meses que no le funciona, contrato a un freelancer medio chafa para hacer el laburo y bueno quedo ahi nomas. pero por lo que me comentas ya me hago una idea de lo que puede haber pasado, basicamente el error estaria en el lado del server.

Comment: Claro, tiene que verificar en el servidor donde tiene alojado su dominio. Si no tiene idea te puede facilitar a ti las credenciales para que revises qué ha ocurrido. Supongo que tendrá la propiedad del dominio ¿? pues puede haberla perdido también, por ejemplo si no renovó la validez del mismo, o si estaba ligado a un contrato de hosting que expiró o cosas así. Es decir, el dominio y el server (hosting) no tienen que estar relacionados obligatoriamente. Yo por ejemplo tengo los dominios en Google Domains y el hosting en otra compañía aparte.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: El dominio no esta registrado, así que o verifican si es otro dominio, o seguramente se perdió el registro y tienen que apurarse a registrarlo nuevamente antes de que otro lo haga, cada segundo cuenta!.

Comment: sisi ahi me facilito las credenciales del host, en este caso es ferozo host ahi entro y te respondo con mas detalle

Comment: ahi entre al hosting, al darle checar estado me sale "el dominio no existe o no tiene dns asignado"

Comment: A. Cedano te puedo contactar por algun medio asi me das una manito?

Comment: parece que la direccion ip esta corrompida o algo, intento buscarla en una pagina que busca direcciones ip y me dice www.wearit.com.ar does not have any IP addresses. en ese caso hay algo que pueda hacer?